# Visual studio - running X number of instances of a project

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, command-line

I know in VS 2013 it is possible to run multiple projects at once, but I need to start a single project with multiple instances (would like to be able to set the number).

The purpose for this requirement is I need to test code that interacts with a server component and want to test its safety if multiple clients are picking at it at, if they make concurrent requests, etc.

**To clarify, I want to start X number of project instances at once.**

Comment: Can't you just launch all or some of the clients outside of the VS?

Comment: Have a look into Process.Start() from the System.Diagnostics namespace.  When you launch your program either manually or through VS, pass in startup arguments (Example, The number of times you want the program to launch), then have Process.Start() launch your application that many times using a loop.  If there are no startup arguments then your program should know to run only the one instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Process.Start()` from the `System.Diagnostics` namespace, and within `Main(string[] args)` check if args has any data.  One of those elements, depending how the arguments are passed in, would be the number of times the program needs to launch itself.  Use that argument in a loop and launch the program again without startup arguments

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    if (args.Length > 0)
    {
        // First element is the number of times to launch itself
        int numberOfClients = Convert.ToInt32(args[0]);

        // Launch the same application multiple times
        for (int i = 0; i < numberOfClients; i++)
        {
            Process.Start(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location);
        }
    }

    Console.WriteLine("I've been launched");
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

### Setting command line arguments from Command Prompt

```
MyApp.exe 5
```

### Setting command line arguments within Visual Studio

[image]

Comment: Where does System.Reflection.Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location point to? Should I not pass the path to the program i want to start multiple instances of?

Comment: @Pipeline System.Reflection.Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location points to itself.  If this program you are creating is to launch "Another" program multiple times, then yes you would pass the path to the program as a startup argument also.  I thought the program you are building is the program you wanted to launch multiple times, hence having itself launch itself a set number of times.

Answer (score 2):

You just start the instance without debugging: DEBUG -> Start Without Debugging (or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd>). You can start another instance without debugging while one is already running. This way you can have several instances at the same time.

EDIT:

You can always invoke the exe from a command line and have a script looping through it several times. The command below did the trick for me:

```
for %i in (1 2 3 4 5) DO myApp.exe
```

If you are running a command line program to have it in separate command line windows you start it with `start cmd /k`

```
for %i in (1 2 3 4 5) DO start cmd /k myApp.exe
```

Only probably use an absolute path to run your program because the new command line dialog is oppened in a default directory. And apply **`/k` switch** which will execute the program after the command line is opened.

Comment: I know I can do it manually, is there a way to automate this? What if I wanted 100 clients?

Comment: Okay, didn't know yo meant an automatic start. Can you add this to the question?

Comment: Is there a way for each of the executables to appear in its own console window

Comment: @Pipeline Added a command to run each instance in a separate command line.